# Can you enter US preclearance at YVR, have your US NEXUS interview, then leave the airport?

Tags: pre-clearance, nexus, yvr

Presumably yes, but I'm wondering on any risks I'd be taking on by doing so?

I am a Seattle based green card holder, and unable to get a NEXUS interview appointment before my global entry expires.
I'm planning on a driving up to Vancouver for the weekend, and purchasing a refundable 1-way ticket to the US. I could then do the Canadian side of the NEXUS interview, go through US Preclearance, do the US side of the interview, then leave. Once left, I would try to cancel the ticket if possible and get my money back.
[After passing through US customs at YVR can you get back out?](https://travel.stackexchange.com/q/115828/140315) indicates it may be more tricky to actually get out of US Preclearance, but presumably there's a way. Who would I have to talk to get out of the area?

In addition, is there a risk to my NEXUS application if I'm open and honest about my reasons for taking these steps?

i.e. at US precleareance: "why were you in Canada?" - "To get my NEXUS interview".

Then back at the Canadian border leaving preclearance:
"Why did you enter preclearance then leave?" - "To get my US NEXUS interview, then continue my visit to Vancouver".

Comment: https://www.cbp.gov/travel/trusted-traveler-programs/nexus/nexus-enrollment-arrival This page, though focussed on CBSA Enrollment on arrival, mentions "the U.S. interview with CBP will follow at Canadian airport preclearance locations for applicants departing from Canada to the United States". The address also indicates U.S. Departures, so I assumed this would require preclearance to get to

Comment: YVR press release and global news also indicate this "Applicants must first book and hold an interview with CBSA officials at their office in YVR. They must then complete a second, separate interview with U.S. customs officials in the pre-clearance area of the airport." https://globalnews.ca/news/9601964/nexus-offices-reopen-at-yvr/

Comment: FYI: If you submit your Global Entry renewal application before its expiration date, you get a 24 month grace period. I'm  about 6 months into my grace period and so far it's been fine. I hope they manage to actually process the renewal in the next 1.5 years! Geez.

Comment: @mic thanks for the update, I'll remove my comment

Comment: I don't suppose you can reach preclearance without a boarding pass for a flight to the US.

Comment: Thanks @Hilmar, unfortunately once you've been conditionally accepted to NEXUS you cannot renew your Global Entry. You need to either complete the NEXUS enrollment, or otherwise cancel the NEXUS application to then renew Global Entry. Tricky situation I'm in!

Comment: @ElFik: I feel for you. It's just mindboggling how long the renewal takes.